# Tell gem to use existing libraries inside Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Nokogiri can be installed on my server only with `--use-system-libraries`. Otherwise it will fail because of libxml2 incompatibilities.

I want to run `bundle install` through a command like `railshoster deploy` which includes several things, including `bundle install`.

But it gives errors when installing nokogiri. Is there a way to mention in `Gemfile.lock` that for Nokogiri it has to use existing libraries?

What is the right syntax inside Gemfile.lock? `gem nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries` does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an environment variable:

```
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install
```